# Postgresql - Unix time stamp from week of year

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I would need to get the UNIX timestamp of a date and a week.

I solved the Date part like this:

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM ('23/01/1980')::timestamp)
```

But cannot figure out how to do the same for the week of the year. For example:

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM ('3-1980')::timestamp)
```

I need the timestamp of the first day of week 3 of the year 1980.

Comment: By "week 3", do you mean week number per ISO-8601's definition "The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday"?

Comment: You mean this `SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM to_date('1980','YYYY')+interval '3 weeks')`?

Comment: @JimJones thank you this worked. Can you post this as answer please, so i can mark it as accepted? EDIT: actually not, it is shifted by a few days. the concept works but its shifted.

Comment: @sharkyenergy I believe `2 weeks` is what you're looking for, as it gives the date for the first day of the 3rd week of 1980, although it would give you only the amount of days (15 days) and not the real weeks

Comment: @sharkyenergy perhaps this might be more accurate `SELECT to_date('3-1980','WW-YYYY');`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [ISO-8601](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers) definition of "week", you can use this somewhat brute force-ish method:

```sql
select min(val),extract(epoch from min(val))
from generate_series('1980-01-01'::timestamp,'1980-01-20'::timestamp,'1 day') dt(val)
where extract(week from val) = 3
```

Result:

```
| min                 | date_part |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 1980-01-14 00:00:00 | 316656000 |
```

If your week values come from a table, you can extract the information and generate the appropriate value for each row:

```sql
select src.week_info as week_info
      ,min(list.dt)::date as first_day
      ,extract(epoch from min(list.dt)) as epoch
from (values ('3-1980'),('21-2012'),('47-2001')) src(week_info)
     cross join lateral (values (string_to_array(src.week_info,'-'))) arr(week_info)
     cross join lateral (values ((arr.week_info[2] || '-01-01')::timestamp,arr.week_info[1]::int)) cnv(start_date,week_num)
     cross join lateral generate_series(cnv.start_date + ((cnv.week_num - 2) || ' weeks')::interval
                                       ,cnv.start_date +  (cnv.week_num      || ' weeks')::interval
                                       ,'1 day') list(dt)
where extract(week from list.dt) = cnv.week_num
group by src.week_info
order by min(list.dt)
```

Result:

```
| week_info | first_day  | epoch      |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| 3-1980    | 1980-01-14 |  316656000 |
| 47-2001   | 2001-11-19 | 1006128000 |
| 21-2012   | 2012-05-21 | 1337558400 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating year and week of the year and then convert it to date with `to_date()` using the pattern `'IYYYIW'`, e.g. `to_date(concat(1980,3),'IYYYIW')` to get the beginning of the 3rd week of 1980.

```
SELECT 
  to_date(concat(1980,3),'IYYYIW'),
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM to_date(concat(1980,3),'IYYYIW'));

  to_date   |  extract  
------------+-----------
 1980-01-14 | 316656000
```

If you're only interested in adding a certain amount of weeks to a date, just add an interval to it or use `to_date` with the pattern `WW-YYYY` (assuming string `3-1980`):

```
SELECT 
  to_date('3-1980','WW-YYYY'),
  (to_date('1980','YYYY')+interval '2 weeks')::date,
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM to_date('3-1980','WW-YYYY')),
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (to_date('1980','YYYY')+interval '2 weeks')::date);

  to_date   |    date    |  extract  |  extract  
------------+------------+-----------+-----------
 1980-01-15 | 1980-01-15 | 316742400 | 316742400
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2a7ada42364d922e93e19c84a3f083fe)